# DataReader Error with Lazy Singleton Pattern in C# when Manager Called More Than Once

Tags: c#, mvvm, singleton

I'm using the lazy singleton pattern in C# for my data managers. The code in my manager looks like this:

```
 private static readonly Lazy<ConditionManager> singleton = 
                new Lazy<ConditionManager>(() => new ConditionManager());
 public static ConditionManager Instance { get { return singleton.Value; } }
```

Then in my code, I am trying to see if the item exists before I create it:

```
 //see if condition exists. If it doesn't then create it.
            List<Condition> conditions = ConditionManager.Instance.Select
                              (question.Id, ConditionType.ProjectQuestion);
            Condition c;
            if (conditions.Count == 0)
            {

                c  = new Condition(question.Id, ConditionType.ProjectQuestion, ReleaseId);
                c.Id = ConditionManager.Instance.Insert(c);
            }
```

The problem is that, when I call the Insert, I get the dreaded error: "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first." I have found a workaround (I have one call to the ConditionManager that both checks to see if it exists and then returns either the existing one of the newly created one), but what is the proper way to handle this? How do I close the first instance?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] we can use to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Maybe Singleton isn't the right pattern here...

Comment: How are Select and Insert implemented?

Comment: This error is related to Command and DataReader objects, so you should provide this part of the code.